# Using internal in package gives error

Tags: actionscript-3, package, visibility

I'm trying to place a class into a package where another public class is placed. The documentation says that only one external visible declaration can be put in a package.

So i declare the second class internal. But then it gives the following error:

> 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: character.AnimatedCharacterClass, character.CharacterPositions

The code I use is:

```
internal class CharacterPositions
{
    public static const BEGIN_WALK:String = 'begin_walk';
    public static const END_WALK:String = 'end_walk';
    public static const STAND:String = 'stand';     
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i have to put the second class outside the package. It still confuses me though.